# List View Threshold error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, aspx, spquery, list-view-threshold

I have a unique problem. I'm getting LVT error when running a script that displays every users' files that they have checked out across all libraries in a web scope in production. Here are a few methods I've tried:

- I have SPQueryThrottle overriden
- Most of the libraries' columns indexed
- Just for the heck of it, I changed the LVT in Resource throttle from central admin to 50K and still get error.

Can anyone give me an answer as to what else I can try?

Comment: Are you using a search results web part? Do you need all users checked out items? Try: CheckoutUserOWSUSER:{User.LoginName}

Comment: No, I'm using a custom application page to display checked out files from all users. Please advise.

Comment: Is the field in your Where clause indexed (I assume you're using CAML)? Also using search is the way to go here. It executes quicker and is not bound to any restrictions (at least in 2013).